# Are incorrect/spam mail id skipped by EXM?

Tags: exm

Can anyone explain me about Spam Filter and Spam rules for mail server?

My questions are:

1) How EXM ensures that there any functionality, Suppose I am entering the wrong email which is not valid. Weather EXM having functionality to skip the invalid mail or it will send the same campaign?

Please clear the doubts

Thanks

Comment: Which version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On high level, if from list of email ID let's assume 2 email ID's are wrong then EXM will skip those ID's.

You can follow below details to get information about wrong email ID's.

1. Create a Email campaign.
2. Add all the data which you want and go to Delivery tab.
3. Now check Notify these email addresses when the message delivery is complete checkbox.
4. Add email ID which you want to get report.

[image]

5. Now You need to go to Sent email campaigns.
6. Go to to the one which you triggered.
7. Then Now click on Recipients activity.
8. Then Click on Failed recipients.

[image]

9. This will give exactly what is the reason that why exchange server ignored it to send/deliver including wrong email ID's.
10. Email report from first part will give how many failed.

Hope this will help you to resolve the doubt you have.

Comment: Thank you so much, much much helpful

Comment: Welcome, Always happy to share what I learnt.